# How to collect values of selected radiobuttons from each views in Fragment

Tags: android

How to collect the values of selected radiobuttons from all the sliding views in Fragment?

Note : The layout is same for all the views which is dynamically generated.

Any suggestions? Would HashMap help me? If yes can someone help me with sample code. Thanks

**LayoutFragment.java:**

```
public class LayoutFragment extends Fragment {
    int fragVal;
    private String[] application = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight" };                     
    private String[] device = { "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen" }; 
    private RadioGroup radioGroup1;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup2;
    private RadioButton btn;
    private RadioButton btn2;
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    RadioButton button1;
    RadioButton button2;
    Button selectall;
    Context thiscontext;

    static LayoutFragment init(int val) {
        LayoutFragment truitonFrag = new LayoutFragment();
        // Supply val input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("val", val);
        truitonFrag.setArguments(args);
        return truitonFrag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        thiscontext = container.getContext();
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        Button myButton = (Button) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                responseText.append("");

                // Get selected radiobuttons
                if (radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 1 : " + text1);
                }

                if (radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 2 : " + text2);
                }


                Toast.makeText(
                        thiscontext,
                        "Data Posting : APPLICATION : "
                                + text1 + " \nDEVICE : " + text2,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });


        //Draw Radiobuttons

        radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout = (ViewGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        for (int i = 0; i < application.length; i++) {
            button1 = new RadioButton(thiscontext);
            button1.setId((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
            button1.setText(application[i]);
            hourButtonLayout.addView(button1);

            radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup2,
                                int checkedId2) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup2.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup2.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup2.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                if (btn.getId() == checkedId2) {
                                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(thiscontext,
                                            "You selected : " + text1,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout2 = (ViewGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio2); 
        for (int i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
            button2 = new RadioButton(thiscontext);
            button2.setId((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
            button2.setText(device[i]);
            hourButtonLayout2.addView(button2);

            radioGroup2
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup,
                                int checkedId) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn2 = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                if (btn2.getId() == checkedId) {
                                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(thiscontext,
                                            "You selected : " + text2,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

        return layoutView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using two groups of radiobuttons? Would it not suffice to have one group and then check what list the selected value was originally from?

Comment: I see you have a button called "selectAll", I'm guessing this means you want the user to be able to select more than one answer from each group. This is not done with RadioButtons, but with CheckBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what it is you want to do here. But if it is to have the user select one radiobutton from either of your lists and then get that answer, then I suggest you do the following:

1) Use ArrayList for your lists of choises instead of arrays.

2) Also have an ArrayList with all the choises (just make it by joining the two lists).

3) Only have one group of RadioButtons

4) In your onCheckedChanged for that group figure out what list the choice was from by using .contains(item) on your ArrayLists

You could alternatively use a HashMap, but if you only plan to have two different lists, you don't have to.